# QMetaObject::invokeMethod fails to invoke a QML/JS function

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtcore

This looks to be a by-the-book simple thing to do, but for some mysterious to me reason fails.

```
Flickable {
    objectName: "flickable"

    function gotoXY(x, y) {
        ...
    }
}
```

#### C++

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(flickable, "gotoXY", Q_ARG(qreal, pos.x()), Q_ARG(qreal, pos.y()));
```

`flickable` is a `QObject*` and is indeed verified to be the appropriate object by outputting its `objectName`. But the method cannot be found:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method QQuickFlickable_QML_1::gotoXY(qreal,qreal)
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried QVariant instead of qreal?

Comment: @LaszloPapp - this works, thanks! I expected that `qreal` will automatically work in QML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `qreal` with `QVariant`, so write something like this:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(flickable, "gotoXY",
                          Q_ARG(QVariant, pos.x()),
                          Q_ARG(QVariant, pos.y()));
```

The reason is that JS arguments like that are interpreted as QVariant with QML. Javascript is not a strongly typed language, so there is no direct mapping between C++ types (even registered) and javascript as such.